# Problems updating quantity in menuitem in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an application that through a thread generates the load of the people that belong to a specific condition, but the number is not updated in the menuitem notification.

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    //En esta parte llamaremos nuestro item que creamos en menu
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
    setBadgeCount((LayerDrawable) item.getIcon(), String.valueOf(Const.NOTIFICA_PERSON_ACTIVE));
    /*Llamamos nuestro método setBadgeCount y enviamos los argumentos que seria el icono y el número de notificaciones */
       threadAlertNotify = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                            int migrationLapse = 15 * 1000;
                            List<enConfiguration> lst = new ArrayList<enConfiguration>();
                            lst = appdbConfig.getAllConfiguration();
                            if (lst.size() > 0) {
                                migrationLapse = lst.get(0).getMigrationLapse() * 1000;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(migrationLapse);
                            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
                            setBadgeCount((LayerDrawable) item.getIcon(), String.valueOf(Const.NOTIFICA_PERSON_ACTIVE));
                            Log.v("Hilo3", "3AlertNotifiTrue - "+String.valueOf(Const.NOTIFICA_PERSON_ACTIVE) + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        threadAlertNotify.start();

    return  true;
}

public void setBadgeCount(LayerDrawable icon, String count){
    //Creamos una instancia de nuestra clase Circle
    CircleNoty circle=new CircleNoty();
    //Llamamos nuestro método setCount y enciamos el numero de notificaciones
    circle.setCount(count);
    /*Mutable no compartirá su estado con ningún otro sorteo.*/
    icon.mutate();
    /*como les mencione anteriormente creamos dos capas una para la notificación y otra para agregar el circulo rojo en esta línea llamamos la capa y agregamos el circulo*/
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, circle);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_notification:
            customAlertDialogActivedPerson = new CustomAlertDialogActivedPerson(MainActivity.this,"N");
            customAlertDialogActivedPerson.show(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(),"customAlertDialogActivedPerson");
            return true;
        case R.id.btnSalir:
             //Toast.makeText(this,"Salir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            CloseSession();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In that thread I should change the number but nothing happens, until I click on the icon, it seems that it needs to refresh the icon, there will be a code to refresh it every time the thread is executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxXXp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are not calling
invalidateOptionsMenu method.
This should be called when you are updating your menu items, and want them to refresh automatically. Additionally, the correct place to do menu manipulations from runtime is onPrepareOptionsMenu method.

From Android Documentation,

> public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) Prepare the Screen's
> standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the
> menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to
> efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the
> contents.

Also, You are using a new thread so whatever you are doing in the background during the menu creation process will finish after the menu will be created for the first time.

Your best bet is to separate the code with logic when you want to update your badge number and store just the number (that needs to be displayed in the menu) somewhere else, so you could access it from the onPrepareOptionsMenu method. Then, every time you want to refresh the icon, call invalidateOptionsMenu()

On top of the above, remember that when you are updating views in Android, you always need to do it from the Main Thread.

I recommend going through documentation about creating menu in android [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu)